# Does Enum have any downsides to using

Tags: c++

Recently I found out that there is such a thing as enumerations in C and C ++.

It immediately seemed to me that it is very visually convenient.

But, please tell me, does the enum have any negative aspects?

If I use them extensively in my code - will this not lead to some kind of problem in the future?

Comment: "visually convenient"? I'm not sure what that means. However it's not clear what you're asking, enums are the right data type for certain things, but not others. I've absolutely no idea what's a negative aspect of an enum. What negative aspects do ints have?

Comment: You mean it seems too good to be true? Never heard of any too-many-enums-problems.

Comment: Enums can be abused for bad designs, just as any other c or c++ facilities will be allowed to do so as well.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ, why enums can make bad - the design?

Comment: Sadly, some people think strong-typing is a negative aspect of C/C++, so that's one.  You should DEFINITELY prefer `enum`s over `#define`s.

Comment: @al3c, "visually convenient" - visual perception of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Here are the drawbacks of the classical enumerations:
>
> 1. The enumerators have no scope (C)
> 2. The enumerators implicitly convert to implicitly to int
> 3. The enumerators pollute the global namespace
> 4. The type of the enumerator is not defined. It just has to be big enough to hold the enumerator.

This [link](https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/c-core-guidelines-rules-for-enumerations) contains relevant and complete information for the question you asked

Comment: I always thought that a "classical" enum defined within a class or a namespace is scoped (this is not `enum class`).  Are all "classical" enums global regardless?

Comment: @franji1 in C, they are either local to a function, or global. In C++, they can be scoped in a class, namespace, etc.